# Implementing Compound component like mat-select in Angular . Not able to project selected projected content to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I am trying to create a custom select component like mat-select in my own Angular library.

Requirements

1. The component should behave like a select component
2. The consumption syntax should be similar like mat-select

```
<mat-select>
    @for (food of foods; track food) {
      <mat-option [value]="food.value">{{food.viewValue}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
```

Here is what I have done so far.

Created two components

1. dropdown component
2. Option component

HTML for dropdown component

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div>{{'Select Favourite Car' || '' }} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="open-close" (click)="toggleShowState()">
            @if(!isOpen){
            &#x21E9;
            }@else{
            &#x21E7;
            }
        </div>


    </div>

    @if(isOpen){


    <div class="option-container" #panel>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Dropdown.component.ts

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ContentChildren, EventEmitter, Input, Output, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { OptionComponent } from './option/option.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-dropdown',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [OptionComponent],
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dropdown.component.css'
})
export class DropdownComponent {

  isOpen: boolean = false;

  selectedValue: unknown = '';
  selectedOption: unknown = null;

  @Output()
  select: EventEmitter<unknown> = new EventEmitter<unknown>();

   /** All of the defined select options. */
   @ContentChildren(OptionComponent, {descendants: true}) options!: QueryList<OptionComponent>;

  toggleShowState() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.options.toArray());
  }
}
```

Option.component.html

```
<div class="option" (click)="onSelect()" >
    <ng-content>

    </ng-content>
</div>
```

Option.component.ts

```
import { Component, ContentChild, EventEmitter, Input, Output, TemplateRef, ViewChild, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownComponent } from '../dropdown.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-option',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './option.component.html',
  styleUrl: './option.component.css',
  exportAs : 'x-child'
})
export class OptionComponent {

  @Input({ required: true })
  value: unknown;

  selectParent: DropdownComponent = inject(DropdownComponent);
  
  @ContentChild('',{ static: true}) child: unknown 

  onSelect() {
    this.selectParent.selectedValue = this.value;
    this.selectParent.toggleShowState();
    this.selectParent.select.emit(this.value);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){

    console.log(this.child)
  }
}
```

The component works fine to some extent .And I am able to use this library component like below from a demo component in an Angular appp

dropdown-demo.component.html

```
<lib-dropdown (select)="onSelect($event)">
    @for( car of cars ; track car.id){
    <lib-option [value]="car.id">
        {{car.name}}
    </lib-option>
    }
</lib-dropdown>
```

dropdown-demo.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DropdownComponent } from '../../components/dropdown/dropdown.component';
import { OptionComponent } from '../../components/dropdown/option/option.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown-demo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DropdownComponent, OptionComponent],
  templateUrl: './dropdown-demo.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dropdown-demo.component.scss'
})
export class DropdownDemoComponent {

  cars: any = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Volvo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'BMW' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Tesla' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Ford' }];


  onSelect(value: unknown) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Here is how the component looks currently
[image]

Here is where I am stuck

I want to project the content that the user selects in the lib-option component into a placeholder in the parent component (lib-dropdown) to show the user exactly whatever he/she has selected. Not only some data pieces.

Is there any way to do that?

Please suggest any improvements /changes that I need to accommodate in my approach to achieve this.